# Running Python Script on Mac/Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script that I wrote to analyze license plate data with the input being a CSV file and I wrote it on a Mac running Python 2.7.2 but when I try to run it on my work computer which is running Windows 8 I get an error. It gives me an error when it reaches the following line:

```
t1 = datetime.strptime(matches[z][1],'%H:%M:%S')
```

and it says:

```
ValueError: time data 'TIME' does not match format '%H%M%S'
```

How can it work on my Mac but not on my Windows computer? Both have Python version 2.7 installed

EDIT: when accessing elements in 'matches' they are of the format:

```
HH:MM:SS
```

EDIT: here is the full code

```
import csv
import difflib
from datetime import datetime

f = open('06 PM TUES.csv')
reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
data = []
for row in reader:
    data.append(row)

g = open('07 PM TUES.csv')
reader2 = csv.reader(g,delimiter=',')
data2 = []
for row in reader2:
    data2.append(row)

# Find Matches
matches = []
cut_through = []
for x in range(len(data)):
    for y in range(len(data2)):
        similarity = [difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,data[x][1],data2[y][1]).ratio()]
        if (similarity[0] > .75):
            if(data[x][1]!=''):
                matches.append(similarity+data[x]+data2[y])

# Calculate Time Difference
for z in range(len(matches)):
    t1 = datetime.strptime(matches[z][1],'%H:%M:%S')
    t2 = datetime.strptime(matches[z][5],'%H:%M:%S')
    if (abs(t1-t2).seconds < 91):
        cut_through.append([matches[z][0],matches[z][1],matches[z][2],matches[z][5],matches[z][6]])

# Print Results to CSV
with open('results.csv','wb') as test_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
    for i in range(len(cut_through)):
        file_writer.writerow(cut_through[i])
```

and the CSV files that contain the initial data have lines of the following format:

```
HH:MM:SS,PLATE#
```

Comment: is there any leading empty chars while running on windows? "matches[z][1]" looks like a result of regular expression, maybe your regex returns different values on windows.

Comment: post more code, and take a look at the value of `matches[z][1]`, is it different between the two systems? My other guess would be that something in your code is sensitive to windows newlines (\r\n) vs mac osx newlines (\n)

Comment: I have uupdated the question to include the full code

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. When the excel file I exported to CSV was created, there were headings across the top that needed to be removed